# return woocommerce item names from cart only if they are a certain variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm more or less a total newbie to php. My goal is to get the names of items from the logged in user's cart and dynamically populate a GravityForms template with the information. I've successfully managed to do that with the code below, but there are three things that I'm failing to do. **1:** I only want to populate the form with all items of a *certain* variation. **2:** the **echo** function will list all of the item names, but not inside the relevant field, and the **return** function will populate the field, but only with the first item name. **3:** I'd like to have the output items listed with some form of separator in between each item name. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php  
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_beat_names', 'beat_names_function' );
function beat_names_function( $value ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

      foreach ($items as $item) {

      $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];


        $license_id = new WC_Product($product_variation_id);
        $license_string = $license_id->get_formatted_name();

        $beat_id = $item['data']->post;     
        $beat_name = $beat_id->post_title;



        if (strpos($license_string, 'basic') !== false) {

             echo $beat_name;
        }

     }

}?>
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to use **strpos** to isolate the particular item variation I want to target, using a certain word found in the name of the variation option, being "basic". I'm sure there's a more secure way of doing that, but it works for now. The problem lies with the return function I set up inside the conditional strpos statement, being that it will still just return the entire list of cart items, as opposed to only the items that I'm trying to isolate with the strpos conditional.

The ultimate goal is to create a license agreement that is dynamically populated with the relevant information, including the names of the items being licensed. The item variations are different license options that I have available for the products in my store. The purpose of the above code is to filter cart items by license type so that the wrong item names don't get listed on the wrong license agreement at checkout.

Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some more tinkering. I broke it down step by step to help anyone as clueless as I am

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_basic_beat_names', 'basic_beat_names_function' );
function basic_beat_names_function( $value ) {

global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

// the item names you want will be stored in this array
$license_check = array();

// Loop through cart items
foreach ($items as $item) {

  // get the id number of each product variation in the cart. this won't work for "simple" products
  $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];

    // translate that id number into a string containing the name of the product, and the options applied to the product
    $license_id = new WC_Product($product_variation_id);
    $license_string = $license_id->get_formatted_name();

    // check to see if the word "basic" is found anywhere in that string. "basic" is contained in the name of the product option being targeted
    if (strpos($license_string, 'basic') !== false) {

        // if the above condition is met, fetch the name of any products in the cart that have that option applied. The product name will be fetched from the title of the product's page
        $beat_id = $item['data']->post;     
        $beat_name = $beat_id->post_title;

        // store the retrieved product names in the $license_check array
        $license_check [] = $beat_name;
    }

}

    // pull the stored product names from the $license_check array, and format them using implode and concatenation, then return the final result to the form field
    return "\"" . implode("\",&nbsp;\"", $license_check) . "\"";
}
```

As a warning, the **strpos** method is a little hacky. It'll only work properly if your string is specific enough to target ONLY the option you're looking for.

As an example, here's the format for the product variation string being fed into the **strpos** function:

```
item-name-option-one-name-option-two-name – variation #xxx of item page title
```

So, if you want to filter items ONLY by option one, your safest bet would be to write the strpos function like so:

```
if (strpos($license_string, 'option-one-name') !== false) {

    //do something
}
```

When all is said and done, the final result should look like: **"item1", "item2", "item3", etc.**

Then, to do the same with any other option, and output the result in a different field, or separate form altogether, I'll just duplicate this code, and replace any mention of the word "basic" with some different unique string contained in the other option. Don't forget to configure the gravity forms field as necessary too.